# Clustering with correlated variables

Tags: statistics, cluster-analysis

I am doing clustering analysis. There are many variables which are correlated to each other.I want to know, is it fine to include correlated variables? What to do in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can run PCA on the dataset before clustering to get rid of linear correlations.

Comment: I have never use PCA, does this method remove correlated variable? Can you elaborate it more ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the obvious approaches:

- Evaluate whether you need all of them, or can leave away some of them
- Whiten (decorrelate) your data by doing PCA, which is a best practise for k-means anyway

Secondly, you may want to look into **correlation clustering**, which tries to identify clusters that exhibit different correlations within your data set. When your data isn't globally correlated, whitening will not remove these local correlations. Correlation clustering is meant to discover these patterns.

Comment: I have never use PCA, Does this method select data that are not correlated?

Comment: PCA does not select data. It computes an projection matrix such that after projecting your data, your covariance matrix is the identity matrix. If your data already is decorrelated, PCA will likely return the identity matrix as projection.

Comment: So you mean, I can select the variables that are not correlated using PCA?

Comment: PCA does not select variables. It **projects** data, using a matrix multiplication. Obviously, matrix multiplication is not the same as selecting features.

Answer (score 0):

It's advisable to remove variables if they are **highly correlated**.

Irrespective of the clustering algorithm or linkage method, one thing that you generally follow is to find the distance between points. Keeping variables which are highly correlated is all but giving them more, double the weight in computing the distance between two points(As all the variables are normalised the effect will usually be double).

In short the variables strength to influence the cluster formation increases.